# Can a function change the values of the variables from the calling function's scope?

Tags: c, function, ansi-c

Can the called function change the values of the variables from the calling function's scope?

Comment: What do you mean? What variables? Change these variables by accident or by design? Variables passed as arguments or some other variables? Can you please show some code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that shows what you mean? Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well, the easy answer is "Yes."

Comment: What you are referring to as functions, is actually called "scopes". You can find an abridged explanation here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Comment: @DavidHoelzer *Well, the easy answer is "Yes."*  Actually, no.  Using a pointer to change *something else* doesn't mean the pointer itself that was passed can be changed directly.  Using a pointer is just emulating pass-by-reference.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I wasn't responding to the comments, I was responding to the OP.  I stand by my answer.  Yes, you can change the values of variables in the calling function from the called function.  I'm not getting into how since the question is so vague.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer If the question is vague, the answer isn't easy.

Answer (score 1):

See [C pointer](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void funcA(int* a)
    {
      *a = 2;
    }

    void funcB(void)
    {
       int b = 1;

       printf("-> %d\n", b); /* -> 1 */
       funcA(&b);
       printf("-> %d\n", b); /* -> 2 */
    }

    int main(void)
    {
       funcB();
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: That passes the *address* of `b` as the variable.  Your `funcA()` does not change that.

Answer (score 0):

Well it will depend on how you call the function. if you use call by value approach then it can't change the original values but if you use call by reference (pointers) approach then it can change the values provided arguments represent the same variables which you want to change.

Comment: Nit pick: C *only* has call by value. Call by reference must be *simulated* using pointers.

Comment: But even that's not going to change the value of the actual **pointer variable** passed from the caller.  The called function can *use* the value of the pointer variable to change *something else*, but it can't change the value of the caller's variable.  Unless the pointer points to itself.